# Are there any issues with mixing aggregates and non-aggregates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I can do something like this:

```
select sum(table1.column1), table3.column2
from table1
JOIN table2 on table1.t2_id = table2.id
JOIN table3 on table2.t3_id = table3.id
where table3.id = 7;
```

This is perfectly valid code in MySQL, but mixing aggregate and non-aggregates like this is not proper SQL.

In this case, there will only ever be one table3.column2 value for each table3.id so there is no problem with encountering inconsistent values. So, would there ever be any issues performing a query this way?

Is there a better way to write my query that does meet the SQL standards and is valid in MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

Standard SQL would complain about your query, because you have a non-aggregated column that is not in a GROUP BY clause.

MySQL 5.6 also complains, if you use the `SQL_MODE=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

```
mysql> select sum(table1.column1), table3.column2 from table1 JOIN table2 on table1.t2_id = table2.id JOIN table3 on table2.t3_id = table3.id where table3.id = 7;

ERROR 1140 (42000): Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

But in MySQL 5.7, it's more clever. It knows that table3.column2 is functionally dependent on the single row selected in table3, therefore column2 is guaranteed to have a single value.  No error is generated.